# Does Broadcasting a DataFrame spill the data to disk if the memory isn't available to hold the data?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question around spark Broadcast join.
By default the Broadcast hash join size is 10MB.

**case1: we have enough Memory in cluster to hold the Broadcast DF.**

If the DF size is greater than the default broadcast join size, say 15 MB is the DF size, and If I broadcast this DF across all the nodes in the cluster, will it still perform a broadcast join?
since 15MB is greater than default broadcast join size, will it go for any other join even though we have broadcast-ed the DF?

**case2: Not enough Memory in cluster to hold the Broadcasted DF.**

So let us suppose if I have 15MB Data Frame and If I want to Broadcast this Data Frame during the join, and the memory isn't available on say one or few nodes to hold this data.(15MB is a hypothetical number)
Will it fail with out of Memory error or will it spill the data to disk?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to broadcast a dataframe larger than spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold, Spark will issue an error.

I can't back it up by official documentation but I don't think there will be a spill to disk. You need to make sure both the driver and the worker can accommodate the full dataframe.